# Why does the log of a variable declared with string + AND (&&) act differently to doing the same with OR (||)

Tags: javascript, string, variable-assignment, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I am at the beginning of learning JavaScript and came across different behaviour when declaring a variable with strings and && (the string doesn't show if used first) vs Strings and ||.

Edit:

I was essentially wanting to output the string before the Boolean value in the console.log and now realise that due to && going from left to right which is different for || that I need to add the number to both sides like the code below the "Snippet Edit" comment in code below (OR am I still wrong?)

Example:

```js
const passDriversLicense = true;
const hasGoodVision = false;

//OR: Declaring a variable with strings and ||
let shouldDrive = ('1 ' + passDriversLicense || hasGoodVision);

console.log(`${shouldDrive} that she should drive`) // Output in console is "1 true that she should drive"
//AND: Declaring a variable with strings and &&
shouldDrive = ('2 ' + passDriversLicense && hasGoodVision);

console.log(`${shouldDrive} that she should drive`); // Output in console is "false that she should drive" which doesn't have the string before it, like in the OR version IE I would think it should output "2 false that she should drive"

//Snippet Edit
shouldDrive = ('1 ' + passDriversLicense && '1 ' + hasGoodVision);
console.log(`${shouldDrive} that she should drive`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimming out the unnecessary baggage and substituting in the values directly, your question comes down to this:

```js
const one = '1 ' + true || false;
console.log(one);

const two = '2 ' + true && false;
console.log(two);
```

Which should make it clearer what's going on.

In the first case, the left side of the `||` is `'1 ' + true`. This is a truthy expression, so the whole thing evaluates to that: `'1 true'`.

In the second case, with `&&`, not only the left side needs to evaluate to a truthy expression, but the right side does too. But the right side is `false`, which isn't truthy - and `&&` evaluates to the right-hand side if the left side isn't truthy.

You could remove the `+ true`s to get the same sort of effect:

```js
const one = '1 ' || false;
console.log(one);

const two = '2 ' && false;
console.log(two);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But I think I needed to be more clear, see my Edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is called [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

> More generally, the operator (&& and ||) returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all truthy.

This behavior is useful for patterns such as:

```
const myNumbers = [];
const highestNumber = Math.max(...myNumbers) || 0; // If Math.max() returns a falsy value, it will replace it with a 0 instead
```

A similar tool exists for specifically `null` or `undefined` values: the `??` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how logical operators work with Booleans in Javascript.

line#3 `passDriversLicense || hasGoodVision = true //because true || false = true`

line#5 `passDriversLicense && hasGoodVision = false // because true && false = false`

Go through these:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: I do get why the answer is True and False for #3 and #5. it was a question about the string in the log for && not acting the same as || but see now that I need to put the string on both sides of && IE

let shouldDrive = ('1 ' + passDriversLicense &&'1' + hasGoodVision);